# Ubuntu Server on live Internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet-connection

I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 in an office machine with openSSH, DNS and LAMP Server. I also made the IP static and I can access the server in my office premises easily, but when I try to access my server from my home it is not working.

I know I have to make some changes and need to install some firewall (I had just gone through with a couple of posts) but I guess an expert advise will save my time here.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get a “permanent” public IP from your ISP, 
then you still need to set-up the NAT infrastructure in your home router that besides multiplying your single public IP into the required private IPs it also adds a pretty good layer of security. 
In order to run services from your house some routers let you establish a demilitarized zone (DMZ) and/or set port forwarding plus running a firewall. Then if you want to i.e. run an HTTP server and your public IP receives an externally generated request on port 80 the router will route that request to the router’s port where your HTTP server is located, next your HTTP server honors the request etc etc…